# any good 3rd-party google app engine administration consoles?

Tags: google-app-engine

app engine has an online console that comes with the service... but I'm wondering if anyone has built a nice 3rd-party/local running app that perhaps has a nicer UI and more features?  something like MySQL Administrator or SQL Server Management Studio or Toad for Oracle?

Comment: I'm only aware of this http://code.google.com/p/appengine-admin/

Comment: If you have some specific ideas of things that would be nice, create an issue. Explain your use case, and how the new feature would help.